# JBREM000200: Remote connection failed Jboss 7.1 Final

Tags: jboss7.x

When i run standalone.bat i got this error

> 42 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting
>   "pc432:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:
>   java.io.IOException: Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 51 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 55 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 62 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 69 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 78 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 89 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 93 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 08 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 23 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 30 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa of 1347375956 36 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc432:MANAGEMENT"
>   read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Received an invalid messa

Answer (score 0):

this is actually wrong because you are sending http request to non http port 9999

Change Ports like below 
Changing the ports :
management-http from 9990 to 8990
management-https from 9443 to 8443
management-native from 9999 to 8999

Ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201728#sthash.o0m10eDj.dpuf